# How to detect the sender(button) of dynamical created bindings

Tags: wpf, data-binding, dynamic

I create some RibbonButtons dynamically and add them to a group according to an xml file. The follwoing function is carried out as often as entries found in the xml file.

```
private void ExtAppsWalk(ExternalAppsXml p, AppsWalkEventArgs args)
    {

            RibbonButton rBtn = new RibbonButton();
            rBtn.Name = args.Name;
            Binding cmdBinding = new Binding("ExtAppCommand");
            rBtn.SetBinding(RibbonButton.CommandProperty, cmdBinding);

            Binding tagBinding = new Binding("UrlTag");
            tagBinding.Mode = BindingMode.OneWayToSource;
            rBtn.SetBinding(RibbonButton.TagProperty, tagBinding);

            rBtn.Label = args.Haed;
            rBtn.Tag = args.Url;

            rBtn.Margin = new Thickness(15, 0, 0, 0);

            MyHost.ribGrpExtern.Items.Add(rBtn);

    }
```

I tried to use the Tag property to store the Url's to be started when the respective button is clicked. Unfortunately the binding to the Tag property gives me the last inserted Url only.
What would be the best way to figure out which button is hit or to update the Tag property.

Comment: You set bindings for tag and command, but I can't see where you set the datacontext for the ribbon buttons. Do you set it in the xaml?

Answer (score 0):

The datacontext is by default the context of the Viewmodel. The RibbonGroup to which the Buttons are added is created in the xaml file at designtime. I use that construct:

```
MyHost.ribGrpExtern.Items.Add(rBtn);
```

to add the buttons. It maight not really be conform with the mvvm pattern. May be someone else has a better idea to carry that out.

I foud a solution for my problem [here](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/sample-code/SilverlightWPFandXAML/76e6b583-edb1-4e23-95f6-7ad8510c0f88/pass-command-parameter-to-relaycommand.aspx) and use the RelayCommand class. So I can pass objects (my Url) to the CommandHandler.

```
RibbonButton rBtn = new RibbonButton();

rBtn.Name = args.Name;
Binding cmdBinding = new Binding("ExtAppCommand");
rBtn.SetBinding(RibbonButton.CommandProperty, cmdBinding);
rBtn.CommandParameter = (object)args.Url;



private void ExtAppFuncExecute(object parameter)
{

 if (parameter.ToString().....//myUrl
```